# Android AnimatorSet repeat then cancel

Tags: android, android-animation

What I need is an infinitely repeatable `AnimatorSet` (composed of 2 sequential `animations`) but also a way to stop these `animations` in a safe way (i.e. the final state is same as starting state). The stop would happen for example by tapping on the screen.

Major problem I had was when I tried stopping by calling either `animatorSet.end()` or `cancel()`, the animation was stopping either midway or finishing the first of the animations (hence not returning to original state).

I found a solution, which really is a mix of a number of different solutions found on SO.

IMPORTANT: The two sequential animations together create a graceful loop, such that `animation1` takes a `button` slowly to the right, while `animation2` returns it to the left more rapidly. This is why I need the stop to end gracefully, such that it finishes `animation1` and `animation2`, whatever the state is when I want to stop it.

Answer (score 2):

To create a repeatable **`AnimatorSet`**:

```
animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
animatorSet.play(animation1).after(animation2);

animatorSet.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            boolean isCancelled;

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                if (!isCancelled) {
                    animatorSet.start();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                this.isCancelled = true;
            }
        });

animatorSet.start();
```

Now the below method `stopAnimation()` you would call from your `onClickListener` or whatever you need to listen for to stop the `animation` (bear in mind `animatorSet` has to be accessible, make it a field for example).

```
public void stopAnimation(Context context){
        guideAnimationSet.removeAllListeners();
```

In the end I didn't need any `cancel()` or `end()`.
This actually makes sense: once I remove the `listener`, the `animatorSet` will finish the current `animations` and then won't be able to start it again since the `listener` for repeating is gone.

Hope it helps someone!